# How do you use URL.Query().Get() to fill in a SELECT statement using Golang

Tags: mysql, go, request

```
func startHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn_str := dbuser + ":" + dbpass + "@tcp(" + dbhost + ":" + dbport + ")/" + dbdb
    log.Println(conn_str)

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", conn_str)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("DB Error - Unable to connect:", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    table := r.URL.Query().Get("table")

    
        rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM "+ table) //selects all columns from table
        cols, _ := rows.Columns()

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", cols)
```

When i try this, it does not fill in the value that i entered from my website. If i log.Println(table) it does show in my terminal. But it will not display on website or fill in the select statement with table...

Comment: Not like you do, by concatenating strings from an untrusted origin (user-specified query parameter) to build the query. Doing so introduces an SQL-injection vulnerability!

Comment: this is for personal use. I'm just creating a webapp to get the fields of a table that i type in. I'm trying to just get the value of table to fill in the FROM statment

Comment: The error returned from db.Query will probably tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are calling this from an API, there a few things I would add, not mention avoiding wildcard (*) selects.

EDIT: I think I may have misunderstood your question, I will see if I can give a better answer.

You're saying that you have a printed value for table, but no response from the DB?  Other commentor is correct, instead of "_", get a real error and fmt.Println(err.Error()).

EDIT 2: Another good point made by @jub0bs is that this is a huge vulnerability.  Go supports this very well by allowing you to do:

```
db.Query("SELECT * FROM ?",table)
```

instead of what you have currently.

I just ran the following code:

```
results,err := publicDB.Query("SELECT * FROM "+r.URL.Query().Get("name"))+" LIMIT 1"
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    for results.Next(){
        fmt.Println(results.Columns())
    }
```

and it worked.  I called the URL [www.mysite.com/endpoint?name=tablename](http://www.mysite.com/endpoint?name=tablename)

Comment: The objective of this app is just to pull all the fields of a particular table. This is so I don't have to have someone send me the fields of a table, i can just run this and get them.

Comment: Gotcha @sippi181, I wasn't familiar with the rows.Columns() syntax. Check out my last two edits, and also I would suggest doing a LIMIT 1 at the end if all you are getting is the column names.

Comment: I tried using the ("SELECT * FROM ?", table) it still is not working. I get a Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1.

Comment: Interesting, what driver are you using for this?  Native database/sql?  I do my connections with github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql but I would expect it would be the same.  I wonder if it doesn't allow the table name to be variable, as it needs to prepare a query to a certain table.  When you kept it your original way, what error did you get?

Comment: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. also i use github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

Comment: Do this: ```query:= "SELECT * FROM "+table``` and then print that, because that error message sounds like it isn't getting table.  You can then use the query variable as your query string for db.Query

Comment: SELECT * FROM Component
2021/06/16 14:24:28 DatabaseInfo
2021/06/16 14:24:28 SELECT * FROM
2021/06/16 14:24:28 Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1----------

Comment: First of all, separate that: what part is the query itself, what part is the error returned by SQL/it's data.  Second of all, fmt.Println(table) and see what that gives you.  I bet I know what's happening actually.  When you fmt.Println(table), you get the string version.  However the real thing is an object.  What you should do is: ```"SELECT * FROM "+fmt.Sprintf("%v",table)``` to get the string version on the URL query object.

Comment: @sippi181, tell me if you got this working or got any good feedback.  I'm curious and wanting an answer

Comment: sorry, SELECT * FROM Component
2021/06/16 15:01:31 SELECT * FROM
2021/06/16 15:01:31 Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: It seems like your table value is equal to "Component 2021/06/16 15:01:31", or the present time.  When you do fmt.Println(table), what do you see?

Comment: 15:20:15 Listening on port 8080 ...
Component  fmt.Printline
2021/06/16 15:20:18 SELECT * FROM Component begin <-- added a begin before query is called
2021/06/16 15:20:19 SELECT * FROM Component End <-- after it's called 
  fmt.Printline                                             <-- 
2021/06/16 15:20:19 SELECT * FROM  begin   <---- this is confusing part (variable is gone, and it prints again)..? begin and end are just text i added to the println's

Comment: So it is saying that table="Component"?

Comment: EDIT: check my answer again

Comment: I can print my columns to the console, its what's going on in the console that i'm confused about... it prints my query then the results then prints my end of query, then after that it tries to execute query again... not sure if it is the way i'm sending the request from the website or something else

Comment: Ok, reply to this tonight if you haven't figured it out by then, I will take a look at it when I'm off work and see if I can replicate exactly what you are trying to do.